# jquery - slideshow buttons function

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have here a slideshow: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/33/)
 
Codes: CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:240px;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:grey;
}
ul li.active {
    background:black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png" />
    </div>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var maxindex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

var index = 0
var interval = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
var timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);

function traverseSlideShow() {
    console.log("current index: " + index);

    $('#slideshow > div')
        .stop()
        .fadeOut(1000);
    $('#slideshow > div').eq(index)
        .stop()
        .fadeIn(1000);

    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    index = (index < maxindex - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;

}

for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"></li>');
}

$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    index = $(this).index();
    traverseSlideShow();
    clearInterval(timerJob);
    timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);
});
```

As you can see in the slideshow, when you click one of the buttons ([image]) the slideshow goes to a photo that the button you clicked is related with.
What I'm trying to do is very simple, the function accept 1 request every 1 second at maximum so user can not spam-click on the buttons, that means the function should break 1 second with every click and prevent loading a different image for different button through this 1 second(in this 1 second the slideshow should load the photo requested).
I'm trying to make my question more clear, lets say we have the three buttons 1, 2, 3 click on button 1 the function takes 1 second to load the photo(through that 1 second if you click the button 2 or 3 the function doesn't load the photo for 2 or 3), and so on.

Comment: So what you want to do is that the user should not be able to keep continously clicking the button to change the photo? In that case why not set the jQuery attribute as disabled for that button for one second? For that one second the button will be disabled and the user will not be able to do anything even if he keeps clicking. After 1 second the buttons gets enables. And user again clicks or the images changes after 3 seconds (If there is code to change the image after 3 seconds).

Comment: Wats wrong with that?? If 2 is pressed before 1st image is loaded it is supposed to load 2 image ... or do u want it should load 1 image and then 2 image

Comment: @user1145009 please read the first comment by Afzaal, that's what I want =)

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan exactly what I want(first idea) I just need the code

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2QbpR/1/

Comment: @System-x32z I'll post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you tell me what did you add to the script?

Comment: I will post it as answer wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple flag based workaround like

```
var timerFlag = false; // a flag to keep track of the click state
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function () {
    if(timerFlag){// if the click state is true within last 1 sec there was a click so don't do anything
        return
    }

    index = $(this).index();
    traverseSlideShow();
    clearInterval(timerJob);
    timerJob = setInterval(traverseSlideShow, interval);

    setTimeout(function(){ //after a second set the flag to false
        timerFlag = false;
    }, 1000);
    timerFlag = true;// set the click flag to true
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2QbpR)

Comment: @System-x32z see the comments

Comment: +1 i just tried this with delay(). by the time I was modifying with settimeout, you answered .

Answer (score 0):

You can use that jQuery as: 
`$("#attrid").attr("disabled", true);`
This will set an attribute to that button as disabled. Then you can use this JavaScript!
`setInterVal(function(), timeInSeconds);`
And from this again you can remove the disabled attribute from that!

Comment: How can I use this in my function? just add this? `setInterVal(function(), 1);`

Comment: You can use a function for this jQuery. And write the name of that function in the setInterval, And sorry the time should be in milliseconds so use 1000. My bad it was!

Comment: can you set it in the fiddle please?

Comment: Ok, wait for a second please.

Comment: I am not able to set any disabled attribute in it. Not sure why! You can try it. Also you have the setInterval in your code too.